# session data has not been accessing

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to fill the deleted massage in session variable in product_edit method under product controller like this:-

`$_SESSION['msg']="Record has been deleted successfully."`
And then i am redirecting to the list page like this:- `redirect('allinone/product_list');`
and then i am showing the massage on the list page in view like this :-

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){?>
<tr>
  <td colspan='8' align="center" class="error_td"> 
  <?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']);?> </td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

**But the session massage is not echoed on the list page. I can't figure out what i have missed in my code ?**
Could anyone look into this ?

I think the new session has created on every navigation.

I am new in codeignitor framework.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: Don't get confuse between php native session and codeigniter session. These two are different. You are using phps native session. Deal it same as you do in other scripts. Only difference you need to take into consideration is, put session_start() at the begining of the method (if session data is getting invalid). And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Coeignitor Session class does not use native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data
On you product_edit method add this you can access session variable like

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Session variable can be set by

```
$this->session->set_userdata('message', 'hello world');
```

Session variable can be retrieve by

```
$msg = $this->session->userdata('message');
```

In your view you can use session like

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('message')){?>
<tr>
  <td colspan='8' align="center" class="error_td"> 
  <?php echo $this->session->userdata('message');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('message');     ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: i have set the session data on product_edit but on the list there is no value exist in `massage` variable.

Comment: giving eror your code:- Error:- `Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in E:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\views\product\product_list.php on line 1`

Comment: But one thing that its generating new session id `([session_id] => e8d995badaedc2fecb998fca5a35ed75 )` on every navigation. Is this correct?

Comment: this is encrypted session id what CI generates itself, this code is working try again

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set_userdata($userdata);` to set session in Codeigniter. For example:

```
$this->load->library('session'); // loading session library

$userdata= array(
   'msg'  => 'Record has been deleted successfully.'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($userdata); // set session

$user_data = $this->session->userdata  // get session
```

More information about Codeigniter sessions you can found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: How can i access this on list page ?

Comment: the value is blank there see: - `Array ( [session_id] => 69ae248375bc227c2f7326f3ba29fc49 [ip_address] => 10.0.0.15 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0 [last_activity] => 1336824366 [user_data] => )`